# can Perforce diff two revisions of a file with different encodings?

Tags: character-encoding, diff, perforce

Any one know if that is possible to diff a file after encoding changes? The situation is like below:

After I have a file converted from utf8 to utf16. When I do diff, a dialog comes up saying that "one or more of the files is either: *of a type not supported by P4Merge; *a text file that may not display correctly using the encoding". It definitely falls into the second case. There is a dropdown menu letting us choose an encoding manually. However, we can only choose one encoding for both revisions. I want to find a way to diff only against its actual content and ignore the encodings. Is that possible to achieve that in Perforce? If not, what are some good tools to recommend?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

If you've submitted the file to a Unicode-enabled Perforce server with the "unicode" filetype, it's normalized to UTF8 on the back end and a server-side "p4 diff2" operation will be diffing utf8 to utf8, regardless of what encoding the submitting client(s) used.  The files can be synced back out to the client in any other encoding that the content translates to (this is controlled by your P4CHARSET setting) for a client-side diff.